# Is there some way to manually set the global namespace for a particulair function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global

We are seeking an implementation for `set_globals` in the pseudo-code below:

```
def foo():
    """
    GLOBALS: `str`, `print`
    """
    print('apples', 'do I exist?')
    print(str('apples'))

foo_dot_globals = {'print':print, 'str':str, 'globby':1}
# set_globals(foo, foo_dot_globals)

#############################################
#  END OF DEFINING `foo`
#  BEGIN MESSING UP GLOBALS
#############################################

import sys
def print(*args, end="\n", file=sys.stdout, print=print):
    print("SIKE!", type(args[0]), args[0], file=file, end=end)

str = lambda s, *, str=str:\
    int(str(s).lower(), 36)

#############################################
#  END MESSING UP GLOBALS. BEGIN CALLING foo()
#############################################

foo()
```

### DESIRED OUTPUT :

```
apples do I exist?
apples
```

### CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
SIKE! <class 'str'> apples
SIKE! <class 'int'> 647846308
```

### THOUGHTS:

Maybe we could use some combination of `inspect.currentframe().f_back`, `gc.get_referents`, `ctypes` or other tools from one of the more powerful, but scary, standard libraries?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Whatever underlying goal you have, there's probably a better way to achieve it.

Comment: @user2357112 I want to prevent globals referred to from within a function from being shadowed. Things like `print` and `str`

Comment: What, that again? Look, if you're stomping your globals by accident, that's a bug. No amount of technical workarounds you try to apply will save you from having to fix your bugs. Any replacement global namespace you try to use can be screwed up as easily as or easier than the original namespace. Adding complexity just means you have more opportunities to screw up, and it's harder to understand what went wrong once things break.

Comment: Anyway, even if controlling `foo`'s global namespace was a solution to your problem, it'd be easier to create `foo` in a controlled namespace from the beginning instead of trying to set the namespace after the fact. You could do that with `exec`, or just by sticking `foo` in its own module.

Answer (score 1):

You can hijack the global namespace of a function object like this:

```
>>> exec(foo.__code__, foo_dot_globals)
apples do I exist?
apples
```

Comment: This relies on the function having no arguments or closure variables, though.